# C# Using Linq Union method with yield

Tags: c#, linq

I am just trying to understand the different output of almost similar code. The only difference is that in first case i store queries temporarily and then do a union. In second case I do it in one statement.

First outputs
BMW
Honda

Second outputs
BMW
 
Honda
Harley
Enfield

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var queries = GetCar().Cast<Vehicle>();
        queries.Union(GetBike());

        var queries1 = GetCar().Cast<Vehicle>().Union(GetBike());

        //First case
        foreach (Vehicle v in queries)
            Console.WriteLine(v.Manufacturer);
        Console.ReadLine();

        //Second case
        foreach (Vehicle v in queries1)
            Console.WriteLine(v.Manufacturer);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Car> GetCar()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            Car car = new Car();
            if(i == 0)
            {
                car.Manufacturer = "BMW";
                car.Model = "7 series";
            }
            else
            {
                car.Manufacturer = "Honda";
                car.Model = "Civic";
            }
            yield return car;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Bike> GetBike()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Bike bike = new Bike();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                bike.Manufacturer = "Harley";
                bike.Model = "NightRod";
            }
            else
            {
                bike.Manufacturer = "Enfield";
                bike.Model = "Bullet";
            }
            yield return bike;
        }
    }

}
public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {

    }
    public int NoOfWheels;
    public string Manufacturer;
    public string Model;
}
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public Car():base()
    {
        NoOfWheels = 4;
    }
}
public class Bike : Vehicle
{
    public Bike() : base()
    {
        NoOfWheels = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case you aren't using the result of the Union.

The code `queries.Union(GetBike());` does not modify `queries`.

You could call it like this and get the result you're looking for:

```
//First case
foreach (Vehicle v in queries.Union(GetBike()))
    Console.WriteLine(v.Manufacturer);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I tend to dislike code like `queries = queries.Union(GetBike());`, but that is valid.

Comment: sorry my bad. Thanks for bringing to the notice. A lot many answers in short span but will mark your reply as answer as it was the first one.

Answer (score 5):

Union does not append to an existing enumeration, instead, it returns a NEW enumeration, yielding the combined results of both.

In your first example, you are calling union and then discarding the resulting enum.

You could have done:

```
queries = queries.Union(GetBike());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)